# Errors on updating Ubuntu Server

Tags: apt, updates

```
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com hardy-updates/main Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]
Hit http://eu-west-1.ec2.archive.ubuntucom precise/main Translation-en
Hit http://eu-west-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://eu-west-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Translation-en
Hit http://eu-west-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Translation-en
Hit http://eu-west-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com hardy-updates/multiverse Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]
Hit http://eu-west-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Translation-en
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com hardy-updates/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]
Hit http://eu-west-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main Translation-en
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com hardy-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]
Hit http://eu-west-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse Translation-en
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com hardy-updates/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]
Hit http://eu-west-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted Translation-en
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com hardy-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]
Hit http://eu-west-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com hardy-updates/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com hardy-updates/main Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com hardy-updates/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com hardy-updates/multiverse Translation-en

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/hardy-updates/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/hardy-updates/multiverse/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/hardy-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/hardy-updates/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/hardy-updates/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/hardy-updates/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the software sources from Ubuntu 8.04 Hardy Heron are obsolete because Ubuntu 8.04 has reached End of Life. Open the terminal, edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` in nano, and delete all the software sources that have the string *hardy* appearing in them:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

The instructions for using nano editor are always found at the bottom of every page. The only two nano keyboard shortcuts that you need to know are <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> for WriteOut and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> for Exit. When you are done editing `/etc/apt/sources.list` in nano press the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and after that press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the sources.list file. After that press the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit nano.

Then update the list of available software.

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Answer (score 1):

For people that might like one liners:

```
sudo sed -ni '/old_release/!p' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Replace `old_release` with hardy or whatever old release you have.